# Jquery works on fiddle doesn't in my wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'd like to make simple ribbon animation and here's my outcome:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/eg5zC/50/
```

Everything works as intended, but after implementing this in my menu it just stopped working.
I had to change the syntax from div's to ul's but it should not make any differences.

I have added the neccessary function to my private.js file and I can view the function at my site's footer.
here's the IP of my digitalocean dev server:

```
http://178.62.215.130/SV/#home
```

Any ideas? I tried to put the code directly in the footer but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Hello Nik!!
Try this once: 'background-position-x': '0%',
  'background-position-y': '0%'

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this with jQuery? At first glance it looks like it's all achievable with CSS alone, which would greatly simplify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put an console log / alert command inside the `$(document).ready(function()` to see if the file/function are being called and continue from there.
anyway, you can use css3 instead, jquery not necessary here:

```
#SVsocmenu li a
{
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;    
}

#SVsocmenu li a:hover
{
    background-position: 0 0;   
}
```

in your jsfiddle example:

```
#block div a
{
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;    
}

#block div:hover a
{
    background-position: 0 0;   
}
```

link: http://jsfiddle.net/eg5zC/52/

Answer (score 0):

**First**, I recommend following the [formatting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of stackoverflow, and *not* puttings links into code. **Second**, if you specify a fiddle link, please also provide some code (not counting the IP-based one).

**Third**, if you are only using jQuery for animations, I suggest replacing that with CSS transitions. A quick and lightweight addition of a few lines of CSS would eliminate 35 lines of seemingly unnecessary JS:

**CSS code**

```
#instagram a, #facebook a, #pinterest a {
    transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0, 1);
}

#instagram:hover a, #facebook:hover a, #pinterest:hover a {
    background-position-y: 0px;
}
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eg5zC/53/

The first and foremost advantage of any CSS transition over a jQuery animation is that the browser handles the animations itself, which is usually paired with hardware acceleration.

Of course, you can specify easing other than `cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0, 1)`. Among built-in presets are `linear` and `ease-in-out`.